# $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+m^2y=0$, $m$ is a constant. I have to show that $m\in \mathbb {Z} \implies \deg(y)=m$ such that $y$ is a solution of the ode.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+m^2y=0$, $m$ is a constant.

I have to show that $m\in \mathbb {Z} \implies \deg(y)=m$ such that $y$ is a solution of the ode. (I don't think I have to solve the equation just to show this.)

My solution :

$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}X^{n}.$

$y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}X^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}X^{n}$

$y''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n+1)a_{n+1}X^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}X^{n}$

$(1-x^{2})y''-xy'+m^{2}y= y''-x^{2}y''-xy'+m^{2}y=0$

Then,
$(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}X^{n})-x^{2}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)(n)a_{n}X^{n-2})-x(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}X^{n-1})+m^{2}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}X^{n})=0$

$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}-(n-1)(n)a_{n}-(n)a_{n}+m^{2}a_{n}=0 \implies a_{n+2}=\frac{n^2-m^2}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n$

How can I prove it ?

Help please, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have the following, which is valid for $n\geq 0$:
$$
a_{n+2}= \frac{(n+m)(n-m)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n
$$
Let $m\in \mathbf{Z}$ be any. If $m$ is even, take $y(0)=1$ and $y’(0)=0$, (so $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$). Therefore all the coefficients of the form $a_{2k+1}$ are zero (because of the formula above).
Also, as $m$ is an integer, $a_{m+2} = 0$, and as it is even for all $k$, $a_{m+2k}=0$. So, $\text{deg} \ y = m$.

Otherwise, if $m$ is odd, let $y(0)=0$ and $y’(0)=1$. Arguing in a similar way, you conclude that $\text{deg} \ y = m$.